# android multiscreen issue

Tags: android, multiscreen

I am new to android app development. I have to develop my app that fit on multiple screen sizes. I have tried many tutorials from android developer forum and etc. But still I am confused to choose correct layout format for multiple screen and image button alignment. So plz let me know if is there any tutorial or sample android application for this.

Comment: We can hardly provide random examples, only for you to say "already tried that". Could you show us what you've used, and what the problem with those was?

Answer (score 0):

To get started you should look at the [Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/index.html) tutorial.  Defining layouts will handle different screen sizes for you in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the guide topic [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)? That's the best place to start. If you have specific issues trying to implement something, post what you've done and what's not working to get help.

Comment: i have read the topic already, and also done one sample app as what they have told. i have deployed the images for buttons at corresponding folders.(example-drawable/hdpi/mdpi/ldpi) the emulater fetch the images correctly according to the screen  size. but the images are not scaled to fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, 
Did you take a look at the android developer site already? If not you  can check that link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with my Samsung Galaxy 551 phone. The alignment of text box was weird because of pixel variations. Just try with your layouts orientation too. My advice would be not to use any hardcodings. Instead use parameters like fill_parent and wrap_content. If you hard like layout_height="300dip", and when you put your app in small screen phones, the latter layout will get your field out of the screen.